# Why Google maps current location different from desktop browser and laptop browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

why [Google maps](https://www.google.co.in/maps) current location `blue marker` is showing wrong place in desktop browser but in laptop its showing correct place.
Here is my code:

`var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                            longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                            debugger;
                            var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                            var mapOptions = {
                                zoom: 10,
                                center: coords,
                                scaleControl: false,
                                draggable: true,
                                scrollwheel: true,
                                disableDefaultUI: true,
                                navigationControl: false,
                                mapTypeControl: false
                            };
                            map = new google.maps.Map(
                                document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions
                                );
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: coords,
                                map: map,
                                title: "Your current location!"
                            });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference position of current location when you use mobile appliance or desktop pc is base on the way google maps obtaion yu position .. with mobile the position is obtion by gps or by mobile telephon cell .. with desktop the position is obatined by mapping of the position if ip related to you wan/lan ..
this behavior is normal ..